# Oracle Responsys RPL: Render HTML from a String in email

Tags: responsys

Im trying to render html tags from a string in Responsys RPL

```
<#assign text = "<b>hello world</b>">

${text}
```

> Output: <b>hello world</b>

I want it to be

> Output: **hello world**

Are there any metodes for executing the html tag when rendered?

Answer (score 1):

Found it:

```
<#noescape>${text}</#noescape>
```